# Why aggregate function returns asterisk instead of string or binary data truncated error

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008

Here the column a return asterisk instead of string or binary data would be truncated error

```
CREATE TABLE #temp1(a varchar(4))

INSERT #temp1
SELECT MAX(12345)

SELECT*FROM #temp1
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**CAST Integer value to character of variable length:**

`SELECT CAST(12345 as VARCHAR(4))`

> Returns * because the defined maximum size of the variable (4) is not
>   enough to keep the number. It will not produce any error, but * means
>   length too short to display, so result is not correct.

`SELECT CAST(12345 AS VARCHAR(5))`

> Will produce correct result: 12345. Actually, in this case the
>   quantity of bytes specified may be any where from 5 to 8000, or MAX.

**CAST Character value to character of variable length:**

`SELECT CAST('12345' AS VARCHAR(2))`

> Will return 12 because it returns maximum quantity of characters
>   allowed: 2. The rest or input string is truncated.
>
> Once again, in this case the quantity of bytes specified may be any
>   where from 4 to 8000, or MAX.

You can read more [here](http://beyondrelational.com/quiz/sqlserver/tsql/2011/questions/Why-does-CAST-function-return-an-asterik--star.aspx)